# How to set the position of colorbar tiks label to the center

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, ticker

I'm plotting some discrete data, and each color represents a class, and I would like the class(number) to be in the center of each color at the colorbar.
How can I do that? How can I set the position of each tick?
The code to reproduce the example is [here](https://github.com/jc-barreto/Some_tests/blob/main/Test%20Plot%20dicrete%20data.ipynb):

[image]

This is the synthetic data:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random 
    
    # Create data
    l = [2, 3, 4, 5,6]
    n = 20
    labels = [item for item in l for i in range(n)]
    random.shuffle(labels,random.random)
    labels =np.array(labels)
    label_unique = np.unique(labels)
    
    n = 100
    x = np.linspace(613000, 615000, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)
    y = np.linspace(7763800, 7765800, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)
    z = np.linspace(1230, 1260, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=n)
    cpt1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z,labels)),
                  columns=['x','y', 'z','labels'])
    
    l = [2, 3, 4, 5,6]
    n = 60
    labels = [item for item in l for i in range(n)]
    random.shuffle(labels,random.random)
    labels =np.array(labels)
    label_unique = np.unique(labels)
    
    
    cpt2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z,labels)),
                  columns=['x','y', 'z','labels'])

    n = 400
    x = np.linspace(613000, 615000, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-7, 7, size=n)
    y = np.linspace(7763800, 7765800, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-7, 7, size=n)
    z = np.linspace(1230, 1260, num=n) + np.random.uniform(-7, 7, size=n)
    l = [2, 3, 4, 5,6]
    n = 80
    labels = [item for item in l for i in range(n)]
    random.shuffle(labels,random.random)
    labels =np.array(labels)
    label_unique = np.unique(labels)
    
    cpt3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z,labels)),
                  columns=['x','y', 'z','labels'])
    
    cpt = [cpt1,cpt2,cpt3]
    
    legend = cpt1.columns.values.tolist()
```

and this is the plot:

```
    %matplotlib notebook
    import matplotlib.colors as colors
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10)) # Or A? papersize
    ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
    ax.set_xlabel('X-axis', fontweight ='bold',labelpad=20)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis', fontweight ='bold',labelpad=30)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis', fontweight ='bold',labelpad=20)
    ax.grid(b = True, color ='grey',
            linestyle ='-.', linewidth = 0.3,
            alpha = 0.2)
    cmap = (colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan','yellow','orange','orchid'])
            )
    bounds = np.sort(label_unique)
    norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N,extend='both')
    colorz = labels
    
        
    for  count, c in enumerate(cpt):
        
        x = c.x
        y = c.y
        z = c.z
        colorz = c.labels
        
        sctt = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z,
                            alpha = 0.8,
                            c = colorz,
                            cmap = cmap,
                            norm=norm,
                            marker ='^',
                            clim = (0,4),
                            s = 90)
        # and a star to match the bore with the legend 
        ax.scatter3D(x[-1:],y[-1:], z[-1:] + 20,
                     marker = '*',
                     s = 90) 
     
    fig.colorbar(
        sctt,
        ax=ax,
        boundaries=[0] + bounds + [4],  # Adding values for extensions.
        extend='both',
        ticks=bounds,
        extendfrac='auto',
        spacing='proportional',
        orientation='horizontal',
        shrink = 0.5, aspect = 16, pad = 0, 
        label=' Ic',
    ) 
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=0.8,bottom=0,top=1) #reduce whitespace around the fig
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I can't, I don't know why I can't post the code here, it gives an error

Comment: It was to big the code, I have to divide into 2 parts, now its ok

Comment: Maybe `bounds = np.arange(bounds.min()-0.5, bounds.max()+1` to calculate the `norm` nicely around the integers. And `fig,colorbar(...., ticks=bounds[:-1]+0.5)` to have the ticks at the integer positions. Instead of a `BoundaryNorm` you also could use the default norm, and set `vmin=label_unique.min()-0.5, vmax=label_unique.max()+1`